# How to get a list of response fields in YQL

Tags: yql

Given the table answers.getquestion; I was under the impression that "desc answers.getquestion" would provide a list of all the possible response fields for querying answers.getquestion. Instead it mentions question_id as a required field.

Where/How do I get a list like the one mentioned in http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/getQuestion.html under response fields? Also, where can I see the mapping identifying question_id in the request to be id in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YQL, the "desc" command gives a brief summary of the table (ref: [YQL docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/statement_summary.html)). In your example, requesting [`desc answers.getquestion`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=desc%20answers.getquestion) shows some simple info about this table:

```
<table hash="2143dbc888c9ccf3daac6778d0f57a32"
    name="answers.getquestion" security="ANY">
    <meta>
        <author>James Broad</author>
        <documentationURL>http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/getQuestion.html</documentationURL>
        <sampleQuery>select * from answers.getquestion where question_id="20090526102023AAkRbch"</sampleQuery>
    </meta>
    <request>
        <select>
            <key name="appid" private="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <key name="question_id" required="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </select>
    </request>
</table>
```

To your question about the response fields, they will come directly through from the Yahoo! Answers [Get Question API call](http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/getQuestion.html). The YQL table is simply a wrapper for the underlying API, and so the results will simply flow back through YQL.

For example, you can see the results from [`select * from answers.getquestion where question_id="1005120800412"`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20answers.getquestion%20where%20question_id%3D%221005120800412%22) in the YQL console:

```
<Question xmlns="urn:yahoo:answers" id="1005120800412" type="Answered">
    <Subject>Why is there no TITLE tag in the header of answers.yahoo.com?</Subject>
    <Content>Come on, you guys.  It's not valid HTML if there's no title. :) Correction: there's no TITLE tag in any of the edit screens, including the one I'm using to add these details. Sorry, my bad.</Content>
    <Date>2005-12-08 08:22:33</Date>
    <Timestamp>1134058953</Timestamp>
    etc.
</Question>
```

Comment: Sounds like to get the data I want is dependent on how detailed the YQL table is. This makes it a bit unreliable for my purposes, unless I make my own YQL tables that show better details of the table. Thanks Brian.